# Dependent selectbox issue

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-selectbox

I am trying to make two dependent select-boxes. There are two **same** select-boxes and the first selection hides the other one when it is selected, like this:

**1st select-box** 
   Option one 
   Option two (selected)
   Option three

**2nd select-box** 
   Option one 
   Option two (disappears)
   Option three

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write something like this

```
<select id="s1">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
<select id="s2">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

and

```
$('#s1').change(function() {
    $('#s2').empty().append($('#s1 :not(:selected)').clone());
});
```

try it here http://fiddle.jshell.net/zDLMZ/
not optimal, but should work good on not big set of options

Comment: That's exactly what I have been looking for! Thank you, thank you, thank you so much!